# How to get the results of a task run inside a loop that is dynamically included?

Tags: ansible

I have a task file that I execute in a loop as follows.

```yaml
- name: check for existing object
  include_tasks:
    file: api/is_valid.yml
    apply:
      tags: always
  loop: "{{ list_of_objects_to_check | flatten }}"
  vars:
    object: "{{ item }}"
  when: >
    list_of_objects_to_check is defined and
    list_of_objects_to_check is not string and
    list_of_objects_to_check is not mapping and
    list_of_objects_to_check is iterable and
    list_of_objects_to_check | length > 0
```

The included task registers the result as follows.

```yaml
- name: perform a object existence check
  uri:
    url: "{{ rest_url }}/Config/IsValid"
    method: POST
    headers:
      Content-Type: "application/json"
      Authorization: "Bearer {{ access_token }}"
    body_format: json
    body:
      ObjectDN: "{{ object }}"
    status_code:
      - 200
      - 400
  register: result
  delegate_to: localhost
  changed_when: false
  when: item is defined
```

Is it possible to check the results of each uri invocation from the caller?  The registered variable only has access to the result of the last uri check.  Although ansible allows me to use 'item' as the registered variable name the contents are not a syntactically valid variable name so that doesn't work.  Also, its not possible to use a templated variable to register to that would store the result into a item-specific variable.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I went with was to add a task to save the results into a dict keyed by the item.

```yaml
- name: store result into item specific variable
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    _results: "{{ _results | d({}) | combine({ item: result },list_merge='append') }}"
  when: item is defined
```